# 3d surface plot of csv data with R

Tags: r, lattice

I am trying to do a 3d surface plot of csv data with R but I don't know how exactly I would do this. The csv File (`sphere.csv`) is

```
0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0
0,0,0,0.447213595,0.565685425,0.6,0.565685425,0.447213595,0,0,0
0,0,0.529150262,0.692820323,0.774596669,0.8,0.774596669,0.692820323,0.529150262,0,0
0,0.447213595,0.692820323,0.824621125,0.894427191,0.916515139,0.894427191,0.824621125,0.692820323,0.447213595,0
0,0.565685425,0.774596669,0.894427191,0.959166305,0.979795897,0.959166305,0.894427191,0.774596669,0.565685425,0
0,0.6,0.8,0.916515139,0.979795897,1,0.979795897,0.916515139,0.8,0.6,0
0,0.565685425,0.774596669,0.894427191,0.959166305,0.979795897,0.959166305,0.894427191,0.774596669,0.565685425,0
0,0.447213595,0.692820323,0.824621125,0.894427191,0.916515139,0.894427191,0.824621125,0.692820323,0.447213595,0
0,0,0.529150262,0.692820323,0.774596669,0.8,0.774596669,0.692820323,0.529150262,0,0
0,0,0,0.447213595,0.565685425,0.6,0.565685425,0.447213595,0,0,0
0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0
0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0
```

and I was able to read it like so

```
sphere_data <- read.csv (file="sphere.csv", head=FALSE, sep=",")
```

Then I tried to to use `wireframe`:

```
library(lattice)
wireframe(z~x+y,sphere_data)
```

but that gave me an error. Especially, the interpreter seems to choke on the `z` of the `z~x+y` expression. I don't know what that expression means, but I found it all over in other examples in the internet.

**Edit**
As per *shujaa*'s suggestion, `dput(sphere_data)` returns

```
structure(list(V1 = c(0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L,
0L, 0L), V2 = c(0, 0, 0, 0.447213595, 0.565685425, 0.6, 0.565685425,
0.447213595, 0, 0, 0, 0), V3 = c(0, 0, 0.529150262, 0.692820323,
0.774596669, 0.8, 0.774596669, 0.692820323, 0.529150262, 0, 0,
0), V4 = c(0, 0.447213595, 0.692820323, 0.824621125, 0.894427191,
0.916515139, 0.894427191, 0.824621125, 0.692820323, 0.447213595,
0, 0), V5 = c(0, 0.565685425, 0.774596669, 0.894427191, 0.959166305,
0.979795897, 0.959166305, 0.894427191, 0.774596669, 0.565685425,
0, 0), V6 = c(0, 0.6, 0.8, 0.916515139, 0.979795897, 1, 0.979795897,
0.916515139, 0.8, 0.6, 0, 0), V7 = c(0, 0.565685425, 0.774596669,
0.894427191, 0.959166305, 0.979795897, 0.959166305, 0.894427191,
0.774596669, 0.565685425, 0, 0), V8 = c(0, 0.447213595, 0.692820323,
0.824621125, 0.894427191, 0.916515139, 0.894427191, 0.824621125,
0.692820323, 0.447213595, 0, 0), V9 = c(0, 0, 0.529150262, 0.692820323,
0.774596669, 0.8, 0.774596669, 0.692820323, 0.529150262, 0, 0,
0), V10 = c(0, 0, 0, 0.447213595, 0.565685425, 0.6, 0.565685425,
0.447213595, 0, 0, 0, 0), V11 = c(0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L,
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L)), .Names = c("V1", "V2", "V3", "V4", "V5",
"V6", "V7", "V8", "V9", "V10", "V11"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA,
-12L))
```

The data in the csv has 11x11 values. These values are supposed to indicate the height of a point (say z-Axis). All values of the first row in the csv are on the same x axis, and equally so for the values of the second row until the values of the last row. The first values of each row are on the same y axis and equally so for the second values of each row until the values of the last row.

Comment: What does your data represent? With 11 columns, it looks like the dimensionality is too high--which columns do you want to plot? And, for easy reproducibility, would you replace your raw CSV with the result of `dput(sphere_data)` (see [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/a/5965451/903061))?

Answer (score 2):

I got it to work simply using

```
sphere_data <- as.matrix(sphere_data)
wireframe(sphere_data)
```

Hope that helps.

Comment: Yes, this is working *if* I type `wireframe(sphere_data)` into the console. But nothing is displayed if the command is in a sourced .R script.